# returning a value if a String includes the key

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions, object-literal

I have a JS Object Literal (logGroupMap) containing alarm names as keys, and their log groups as values.  Alarm names are passed in with consistent names of varying length but with generated characters at the end each time, so I'm trying to see if the string includes a key from the logGroupMap object literal, and if so I want to get the value associated with that key.

```
  let logGroup = (alarmName) => {
    Object.keys(logGroupMap).forEach((key) => {
      if (alarmName.includes(key)) { logGroup = logGroupMap.key; }
    });
  };

console.log(logGroup(messageDetails.AlarmName));
```

Currently this is returning undefined in all cases.

Comment: shouldn't you do return logGroupMap.key? sorry I never watched that syntax and was skeptic but didn't verify on my own. Well actually I better see the problem now. You are inside the forEach loop there that I'm not sure you can break. But at the end of it you should return the var you populated with the logGroupMap.key (and the var name should be called differently than the function name and declared in the function scope).

Comment: You are reassigning the funciton variable to the value of the mapped value each time. That means even if it finds a matching value, it will keep iterating over til the end of the loop. It would probably be better to return the value if its found instead of reassigning it to the logGroup variable

Comment: You're not returning anything from the function. And `forEach()` doesn't return anything. What are you expecting to log?

Comment: `logGroupMap.key` should be `logGroupMap[key]`.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar this is exactly the answer I needed

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Array.find()` method to search for a matching key.

To access a property dynamically, use `logGroupMap[key]`. `logGroupMap.key` returns the value of the property named `key`, it doesn't use `key` as a variable.

```js
function logGroup(alarmName) {
  let found = Object.keys(logGroupMap).find((key, value) => alarmName.includes(key));
  if (found) {
    return logGroupMap[key];
  }
}
```